# Terraform count calling module output(return) error

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, terraform, hcl

I need to return output of name and id only

root main.tf

```
# Azure Provider configuration
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

module "rg" {
  source              = "../../modules/rg"
  count               = length(var.resource_groups)
  resource_group_name = var.resource_groups[count.index].name
  tags                = {}
  location            = westus2
  lookup              = false
}
```

module/rg/main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
    count    = var.lookup == true ? 0 : 1
    name = var.resource_group_name
    location = var.location
    tags = var.tags
}

output "rg_id" {
  description = "The id of the newly created rg"
  value       = azurerm_resource_group.rg[count_index].id # azurerm_resource_group.rg, this statement will work
}

output "rg_name" {
  description = "The name of the newly created rg"
  value       = azurerm_resource_group.rg[count_index].name #  azurerm_resource_group.rg, this statement will work
}
```

I am getting below error:

A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.

Comment: What is `count_index`? It is undefined.

Comment: If i define, like this,  value       = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name, I am getting , Because azurerm_resource_group.rg has "count" set, its attributes must be
accessed on specific instances.

Comment: And where is `is_default` defined? Is it `module.rg.is_default`?

Comment: i just removed is_default in question , to remove confusion,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following should address your issue:

```
output "rg_id" {
  description = "The id of the newly created rg"
  value       = var.lookup == true ? azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].id : null
}

output "rg_name" {
  description = "The name of the newly created rg"
  value       = var.lookup == true ? azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name : null
}
```

Comment: how to catch at root directory? to use in other module , resource_group_name                                   = module.rg.rg_name but it is not working

Comment: @Vidya Sorry, I'm now sure what you mean? Maybe you could make new question with relevant details if this is a new issue.

Comment: sure, i will do in another hour